# Is it possible to tell exactly what is causing the render function to execute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app and when I click on a navigation bar it is causing a completely un-related component to render.

I looked at the code and can not find the connection.

It does not break anything but I find it bizarre.

I am aware of React lifecycles and was wondering if how I can troubleshoot further to see what is causing it to `render()`.

I noticed that `componentDidUpdate()` is called but I don't know why it is being called by React or what is causing it to update.  How can I troubleshoot further?

Maybe relevant code is, but maybe not.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log('DEBUG: componentDidUpdate() called', prevProps.Modal);
    // Set the state of the form to the data returned from the server.
    // This will allow us to PUT / Update the data as this is a controlled form.
    // That is the state holds the form input.
    // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props) or infinite loop will ocur.
    if (this.props.Modal.data !== prevProps.Modal.data) {

      // becasue the form did not update but populates we must call update manually for both URLs
      this.url.updateURL(this.props.Modal.data.link);
      this.img_url.updateURL(this.props.Modal.data.image);
      this.setState(this.props.Modal.data);

    }
  }
```

prevProps is always the same for each call. i.e. the props do not change.

It is only mounted once and props and state do not change but it keeps updating!

See image:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I would but I don't know what to post.  I don't know what is relevant.  I added a parameter prevProps to componentDidUpdate but it is the same each time.  Will post this.

Comment: I would think the navigation component and the unrelated component that is rendering would be a good start. If you are using redux or context, then the provider for these components would be relevant too

Comment: I am using redux and the Modal component will receive a dispatch event from another component an add button which causes the modal to open.

Comment: Verified that props is not changing.  Verified that state is not changing.  What else can I check?

Comment: I clearly don't understand what causes an update event to fire.

Comment: Great, so seems like a good start. I suggest creating a new [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) and uploading your project there. It's easier to interact with the code and work through a solution there

Comment: Well I read this ... https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

Comment: and it seems simple if the state or props changes?  This will cause an update to fire.  But I verified neither is changing.  I have a suspicion that it is being mounted multiple times but I verified this is not the case.  I will create a more minimal example later.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. If you post a link to a Codesandbox project or upload your minimal example, I can see exactly what is going wrong

Comment: What does *not changing* mean? Two objects are not equal to each other `{} !== {}` ...

Comment: you can try this package in your project: https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render It could help you